Fractional Linear Transformation $(i,1,-i) \to (0,i,1)$
I am trying to find the linear transformation (using the Möbius Transformation) of the following mapping and this has been driving me in circles.
find the fractional linear transformation that maps $(i, 1, −i) \to (0, i, 1)$.
I started off as follows:
$f(z)=az+b/cz+d$; definition of the Möbius Transformation
i.) Mapping $f(i)=0$
$f(i)=ai+b/ci+d$; since $z=i$
$0=ai+b/ci+d$; since $f(i)=0$
$ai+b=0$; cross multiply
$b=-ai$
ii.) Mapping f(1)=i
f(1)=a(1)+b/c(1)+d ; since z=1
f(1)=a+b/c+d
f(1)=a-ai/c+d ; since b=-ai
a-ai=(c+d)i ; cross multiply
a-ai=ci+di ; distribution
a=ci+di/(1-i)
a=(ci+di)(1+i)/(1-i)(1+i) ; multiply the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of 1-i
a=(ci-c+di-d)/2
a=(-c-d)+(c+d)i/2
a=-(c+d)+(c+d)i/2
a=(c+d)(-1+i)/2
iii.) Mapping f(-i)=1
f(-i)=a(-i)+b/c(-i)+d ; since z=-i
f(-i)=b-ai/d-ci ; commutative
1=b-ai/d-ci ; since f(-i)=1
1=-ai-ai/d-ci ; since b=-ai
1=-2ai/d-ci
-2ai=d-ci ; cross multiply
-2((c+d)(-1+i)/2)i=d-ci ; since a=(c+d)(-1+i)/2
-i(c+d)(-1+i)=d-ci
(c+d)(i+1)=d-ci
ci+c+di+d=d-ci
ci+c+di=-ci
di=-2ci-c
d=(-2ci-c)/i
d=(-2ci-c)(-i)/i(-i)
d=-2c+ci
Now have the following equations:
b=-ai
a=(c+d)(-1+i)/2
d=-2c+ci
Since, a=(c+d)(-1+i)/2 and d=-2c+ci then:
a=(c+d)(-1+i)/2
a=(c+-2c+ci)(-1+i)/2 ; since d=-2c+ci
a=(-c+ci)(-1+i)/2
a=(c-ci-ci-c)/2
a=(-2ci)/2
a=-ci
So far I have that:
a=-ci
b=-ai
I am unsure how to go abouts to find c and d.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Please use MathJax for better formatting.

I started with a small edit for introducing MathJax in your question. Feel free to continue.

@Dominique Thank you - I was going to edit this but the OP should learn how to use MathJax.

Since you found $a=-ci,b=-ai,d=(i-2)c$, you are done: $$(a,b,c,d)=c(-i,-1,1,i-2),$$$$f(z)=\frac{-iz-1}{z+i-2}.$$
You thus proved the uniqueness of the solution. You may either check that this is indeed a solution, or reorganize your calculations more methodically to prove existence and uniqueness simultaneously, or explain why you knew in advance there would be a unique solution.
